# C++ data-types, and their effects on executable size

Tags: c++, types, casting, arduino, microcontroller

I'm basically new to C++, aside from attempting to learn the language over 10 years ago and giving up, as I didn't really have a project to motivate me... Anyways, I'm just stating that I'm pretty much a n00b to C++ to let you guys/gals know my current knowledge level. That said, I am fairly proficient with Python and PHP. And since both of those languages are loosely typed, I am not that familiar with the impact type casting in C++ has on executable size, if any.

I am writing an Arduino program to take some data from a couple of ultra-sonic distance sensors and apply the data to a servo control algorithm. No problems with that, but I am now trying to optimize my code, as I'm getting close to the Arduino Micro's limit of 28,672 bytes. My first thought was to change my data types wherever possible to things like short int's and char's, expect it to have either no effect, or to slightly reduce my executable size. What I found is that the executable actually increased in size, after these changes, by a few hundred bytes.

Could someone with more C++ knowledge than I kindly help me understand the reason for this, and why I should, or shouldn't, even bother trying to choose the smallest possible data types for my variables? Obviously the results dictate what I *should* do here, but I really like to understand the 'why' behind things, and after some Googling, I still came up unsure.

Also, if it's not too much to ask; does anyone have some tips, or a link to some info on optimizing C++ code for limited-memory micro-controllers such as the Arduino?

Comment: Have you tried optimizing for size when compiling? `gcc -Os ...`

Comment: I'm a C++ person, but for such a size constrained environment I would just use C.

Comment: @DavidBrown: I'm new to Arduino, C++ and micro-controllers. So I'm not really sure yet how to write code in a different language and then manually upload the executable to the Arduino (their IDE handles compile and upload with a couple of clicks). While I'm sure I could figure that all out, I imagine the lack of Arduino libraries for C would make this more of a challenge than I'm up for, haha. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: @millsj: That's a great idea! I'll look more in to that for sure! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask many things, but this can be answered with an example:

> What I found is that the executable actually increased in size, after these changes, by a few hundred bytes.
>
> ... help me understand the reason for this ...

In general, you cannot predict whether a smaller data type is better or worse, which the small bit of code below will demonstrate.

To see what is going on, you have to look at the assembly code produced by the compiler.  The AVR tool chain has a component that will produce such a listing, typically an .LSS file.  I don't think Arduino supports this.  The assembly listings below are via Eclipse which drives the extended listing by default.

Here is a little section of an LED blink program that can be used to demonstrate your confusion.  It has a brightness value that it sets to the LED in the loop:

```
boolean fadein = true;
int bright = 0;   // we will change this data type int <-> int8_t

void loop() {

  // adjust brightness based on current direction
  if(fadein) {
    bright += 1;
  }
  else {
    bright -= 1;
  }

  // apply current light level
  analogWrite(13,bright);
```

To demonstrate, the **bright** variable is changed between 1 byte and 2 byte int's and we compare the assembly listing:

---

Compare The Increment Line

Here is the listing for just the increment line with two data types:

```
// int bright - increment line - must load and store 2 bytes
// 18 bytes of code

    bright += 1;
 18a:   80 91 02 01     lds r24, 0x0102
 18e:   90 91 03 01     lds r25, 0x0103
 192:   01 96           adiw    r24, 0x01   ; 1
 194:   90 93 03 01     sts 0x0103, r25
 198:   80 93 02 01     sts 0x0102, r24
```

The first column is the code space address, the second column the actual code bytes, and the last column is the assembly human readable form.  LDS is load from memory, ADIW is the add, and STS is storing back to memory

Here is the smaller data type, with the expected result:

```
// int8_t bright - increment line - only load and store 1 byte
// 10 bytes of code

   bright += 1;
 18a:   80 91 02 01     lds r24, 0x0102
 18e:   8f 5f           subi    r24, 0xFF   ; 255
 190:   80 93 02 01     sts 0x0102, r24
```

Note the weirdness of SUBI 255 instead of adding 1 -- that is compiler devs tricks.

So there you go, the smaller data type produces smaller code as you expected.  You were correct! Oh wait, you already stated you where not correct...

---

Compare the function call

But what about function calls?  The analogWrite() method expects an int, so the compiler will be forced to create a conversion if needed

```
// int - needs no type conversion, can directly load value 
// from addresses 0x0102 and 0x0103 and call
// 16 bytes code

 // apply current light level
  analogWrite(13,bright);
 1b0:   20 91 02 01     lds r18, 0x0102
 1b4:   30 91 03 01     lds r19, 0x0103     

 1b8:   8d e0           ldi r24, 0x0D   ; 13
 1ba:   b9 01           movw    r22, r18
 1bc:   0e 94 87 02     call    0x50e   ; 0x50e <analogWrite>
```

LDI is loading the constant, MOVW is moving variable in preparation for call.

```
// int8_t - needs a type conversion before call
// 20 bytes code
 
  // apply current light level
  analogWrite(13,bright);
 1a0:   80 91 02 01     lds r24, 0x0102
 1a4:   28 2f           mov r18, r24
 1a6:   33 27           eor r19, r19
 1a8:   27 fd           sbrc    r18, 7
 1aa:   30 95           com r19
 
 1ac:   8d e0           ldi r24, 0x0D   ; 13
 1ae:   b9 01           movw    r22, r18
 1b0:   0e 94 76 02     call    0x4ec   ; 0x4ec <analogWrite>
```

No need to understand the assembly for the type conversion to see the effect. The smaller data type has produced **more** code.

---

So what does it mean?  The smaller data type both reduces code size and increase code size.  Unless you can compile code in your head, you cannot figure this out by inspection, you have to just try it.

Comment: Okay, I know I'm not supposed to reply just to say 'thanks' here, but holy assembly gods, @jdr5ca, that was an amazingly insightful explanation that really helped me to grok this whole problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

First, take a look to [how to optimize your Arduino memory usage](http://liudr.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/how-to-optimize-your-arduino-memory-usage/) and [optimizing Arduino memory use](http://www.sumidacrossing.org/LayoutElectricity/Arduinos/ArduinoMemory/). also, take a look to [saving RAM space](http://jeelabs.org/2011/05/23/saving-ram-space/).

Comment: Links are not answers.  There needs to be some actual info here.

Comment: @cHao: Normally I would agree, but I did ask for such links as a secondary request at the bottom of my post. Thus, I think the down-vote is a bit unfair. I do appreciate the links provided here! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you have to distinguish between code size and data size. Optimizing data size is likely to increase your code size (and also slow things down), because the compiler needs to put more instructions into the code to convert forth and back between the various possible data sizes.

So, as a rule of thumb: Use the default data size (e.g. "int") for any value, that appears in the data at most a few times. On the other hand, if you have large arrays, setting the optimum data size (e.g. "short", if the value is guaranteed to be in the range -32768 .. 32767) can greatly reduce the memory footprint of your app at runtime.

In your case, where you don't have much data, focus more on optimizing code size: Reduce the number of libraries used, and avoid wrappers etc. pp.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're comments are very insightful and useful. I appreciate you taking the time to help me understand things a bit more. This may be a dumb question, but when I do use a library; does the stuff in that library that I don't use effect the executable size? I.e. would stripping the libraries down to just what I need for the project help at all? Or, would taking code snippets from libraries and using them directly, rather than linking the library reduce the executable size? Or would this all be pointless and counter-productive (which is my gut feeling)?

Comment: The memory footprint of libraries depends a lot on their type: C++ template libraries like the STL containers tend to increase your code size a lot, because they cannot be precompiled. On the other hand, C libraries or C++ libraries, that don't use templates, don't increase the size of your executables, if dynamic linking is used. I am not sure, whether Arduino does dyamic linking, but I'd assume, it doesn't. Having that said: Using classic arrays instead of std::vector or self-written linked lsits instead of std::list might decrease the executable size notably.

Comment: The compiler produces code for everything in source files and produces object files.  The linker takes all the object files and combines to produce the executable.  Any function in a library not referenced in your code is not included in the binary.  So your final binary size does not benefit by stripping libraries.  You can easily test this by pasting in a giant chunk of code in your program that is never called -- you will see the binary size not change a byte.

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest memory consumers are floating point numbers (both in RAM and FLASH). Ram because the types are larger than integers and Flash because the Arduino does not have a floating point unit. Thus all floating point operations will result in a larger executable.

Also take care that using libraries may link lots of not really needed stuff that consumes significant amounts of your memory.

Having said that: without any more details on your code it is pretty hard to determine why you have such a large memory footprint.

Comment: I know why I have a large memory footprint - a lot of code! haha. (a lot for the Arduino Micro that is). And it wasn't optimized too well before I posted this. I had been working to optimize the code in more straight forward ways, I just didn't understand the type-setting / binary size issue, but a few of the great posts here cleared it up! That's a good thing to remember about FP on the Arduino, I do have a few code snippets from 3rd parties that used FP, and I've converted those to integer. You're right, it helped significantly!